# Is there any way to divide an equation by another in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, eval, equation

Here's my guess:

```
TempFunc1 = input('Eqution1: ')
TempFunc2 = input('Eqution2: ')
TempFunc3 = eval(TempFunc1/TempFunc2)
```

I have defined `x` as a symbol and enter `x**2-4` for `Equation1` and `x-2` for the other.
And I Have imported `*` from `sympy`.
the whole code:

```
import os
from sympy import *
from random import randrange
x = Symbol('x')
Variable = input('Eqution: ')
TempFunc1 = Variable.translate(str.maketrans('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))
TempFunc2 = TempFunc1.replace('^', '**')
TempFunc3 = input('Eqution: ')
TempFunc4 = eval(TempFunc2/eval(TempFunc3)
Func = eval(TempFunc4)
Func_prime = Func.diff(x)
Func = lambdify(x, Func)
Func_prime = lambdify(x, Func_prime)
x = randrange(100)
print('attempts:')

while Func(x) != 0:
  Derivative = Func_prime(x)
  Function = Func(x)
  Divide = Function/Derivative
  x = x-Divide
  print(x)
else:
  Ans = round( x , 31  )
  print("answer:")
  print(Ans)
  os.system('pause')
```

Comment: I guess you need `eval(TempFunc1) / eval(TempFunc2)`. But [don't use `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Can you please add the expected output for the equations you gave?

Comment: @ori6151 Equation1 : x**2-4 Equation2 : x-2

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I have translation filter in input that convert alphabets into x symbol if you mean this.

Comment: *TempFunc12* are strings. What do you expect *TempFunc3* to be?

Comment: If you want the output to be `x+2` (because `x²-2²` => `((x-2)*(x+2))/x-2`) then that's very advanced.

Comment: @ori6151 no I just want (x**2-4)/(x-2). I have code that solves equation with Newton's method no need for the answer : x+2

Comment: Since you seem to be using (or rather trying to use...) sympy, you should have a look at sympy.sympify().

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you just want your program to add a `/` between the two equations?

Comment: @ori6151 yes but then I want to solve it by another code. but if i say correctly it should be int.

Comment: let me ad  the whole code

Comment: edited now you can see the whole code i am working on.

Comment: Replacing ```eval``` with ```sympify``` would be useful.